# VBA - Date and Time Inequalities

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excell spreadsheet with date and time data formated as (2016-05-14 10:34:28.0). I cant seem to create a series of inequalities between two cells of the same such format. I have never come across cells with both dates and times and dont know what type of variable values to give them in VBA. My goal is to compare a series of columns with the same date/time format using inequalities and determermine a due date.

```
For i = 4 To numrows

start_time_day = DateValue(WorksheetFunction.Text(updater.Cells(i, 12), "dd/mm/yyyy"))
start_time_time = TimeValue(WorksheetFunction.Text(updater.Cells(i, 12), "hh:mm:ss"))
latest_due_day = DateValue(WorksheetFunction.Text(updater.Cells(i, 21), "dd/mm/yyyy"))
latest_due_time = TimeValue(WorksheetFunction.Text(updater.Cells(i, 21), "hh:mm:ss"))
latest_commit_day = DateValue(WorksheetFunction.Text(updater.Cells(i, 22), "dd/mm/yyyy"))
latest_commit_time = TimeValue(WorksheetFunction.Text(updater.Cells(i, 22), "hh:mm:ss"))
order_taken_day = DateValue(WorksheetFunction.Text(updater.Cells(i, 10), "dd/mm/yyyy"))
order_taken_time = TimeValue(WorksheetFunction.Text(updater.Cells(i, 10), "hh:mm:ss"))
compdate_day = DateValue(WorksheetFunction.Text(updater.Cells(i, 1), "dd/mm/yyyy"))
compdate_time = TimeValue(WorksheetFunction.Text(updater.Cells(i, 1), "hh:mm:ss"))
arrival_day = DateValue(WorksheetFunction.Text(updater.Cells(i, 16), "dd/mm/yyyy"))
arrival_time = TimeValue(WorksheetFunction.Text(updater.Cells(i, 16), "hh:mm:ss"))

servreqdesc = updater.Cells(i, 17)                                        'PULL INFO FROM UPDATE FILE
restake = updater.Cells(i, 30)
onproj = updater.Cells(i, 31)
workloc = updater.Cells(i, 35)
staked = updater.Cells(i, 6)
mdcomp = updater.Cells(i, 29)
compstatus = updater.Cells(i, 20)
start_time = start_time_day + start_time_time
latest_due = latest_due_day + latest_due_time
latest_commit = latest_commit_day + latest_commit_time
order_taken = order_taken_day + order_taken_time
compdate = compdate_day + compdate_time
arrival = arrival_day + arrival_time




'----------------------------Date Missed-----------------------------------
ElseIf (servreqdesc = "FIELD\MISSDIG\ELEC\M" Or servreqdesc = "FIELD\MISSDIG\GAS\M") Then
    ElseIf (restake = "Y" Or servreqdesc = "FIELD\MISSDIG\GAS\EM" Or servreqdesc = "FIELD\MISSDIG\ELEC\E") Then
        If (start_time = "(null)" And latest_due < order_taken) Then
            em_time = order_taken
            ElseIf (start_time = "(null)" And latest_due > order_taken) Then
                em_time = latest_due
                ElseIf start_time > order_taken Then
                        em_time = start_time
                        Else
                        em_time = order_taken
                    End If
```

Comment: singly a date, or split both will be date type, and you can treat them as dates I believe.  =DATEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy")) and =TIMEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss"))  you can just use text also.

Comment: I added code, when i tried your method i recieved a type mismatch in this line - (If (start_time = "(null)" And latest_due < order_taken) Then).

Answer (score 0):

Dates are just numbers.

- 1 Day = 1
- 1 Hour = 1/24
- 1 Minute = 1/24/60
- 1 Second = 1/24/60/60
- The value 1 = 1/1/1900
- -1 results in ##### because negatives aren't allowed

[Here is a list of VBA Date Functions](http://www.classanytime.com/mis333k/sjdatetime.html)